# kubernetes Failed to create tags for load balancer security group

Tags: kubernetes

when I create a service in kubernetes, I see that controller-manager will create a security group and a new rule of minion's security group. with some warning:

```
W1028 05:34:44.104402       1 aws.go:1755] Failed to create tags (too many attempts): InvalidParameterValue: Value ( '' ) for parameter Tag key is invalid. Tag key cannot be null or empty.
    status code: 400, request id: []
E1028 05:34:44.104450       1 aws.go:1830] error creating load balancer security group: error tagging security group: InvalidParameterValue: Value ( '' ) for parameter Tag key is invalid. Tag key cannot be null or empty.
    status code: 400, request id: []
E1028 05:34:44.104500       1 servicecontroller.go:173] Failed to process service delta. Retrying: failed to create external load balancer for service default/nginx-service: error tagging security group: InvalidParameterValue: Value ( '' ) for parameter Tag key is invalid. Tag key cannot be null or empty.
    status code: 400, request id: []
```

is there anything I missed when I setup my kubernetes cluster?

---

added on 12/22/2015

still find this problem, when creating ELB

```
W1222 04:38:51.220684       1 aws.go:1571] Failed to create tags (too many attempts): InvalidParameterValue: Value ( '' ) for parameter Tag key is invalid. Tag key cannot be null or empty.
    status code: 400, request id:
E1222 04:38:51.220726       1 aws.go:1647] error creating load balancer security group: error tagging security group: InvalidParameterValue: Value ( '' ) for parameter Tag key is invalid. Tag key cannot be null or empty.
    status code: 400, request id:
E1222 04:38:51.220780       1 servicecontroller.go:187] Failed to process service delta. Retrying: Failed to create load balancer for service default/nginx: error tagging security group: InvalidParameterValue: Value ( '' ) for parameter Tag key is invalid. Tag key cannot be null or empty.
    status code: 400, request id:
```

```
kubectl version
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"1", GitVersion:"v1.1.2", GitCommit:"3085895b8a70a3d985e9320a098e74f545546171", GitTreeState:"clean"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"1", GitVersion:"v1.1.3", GitCommit:"6a81b50c7e97bbe0ade075de55ab4fa34f049dc2", GitTreeState:"clean"}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm the author of the code here.  Something definitely isn't right, and I can't see how you hit the case based on reading the code.  What version of kubernetes are you running (a release, or running from source)?  And how did you install - did you use kube-up?

Also, when you first start the controller-manager, it should log one of these two messages: either "AWS cloud filtering on tags: ..." or ""AWS cloud - no tag filtering".  Which of the two does it log, and if the first what tags is it filtering on?

Comment: I use download release 1.0.6, and setup the cluster step by step(I set no tag for the instances), and the controller-manager says "aws.go:597] AWS cloud - no tag filtering"